# Swift 4 key-value observe in background

Tags: swift, concurrency, swift4

I want to observe a property with key value observing and send change events over a connection.

The issue I have is that the GCD based queues are for tasks, not long running processes.

I want to be able to prevent the function from returning, but still listen for key-value changes and send them over the connection asynchronously.

Example:

```
func f(con: Connection) {
   objCKVObservable.observe(\.path) {(a, b) in
       con.send("some changes")
   }


   // Cannot let this function return as the connection is auto closed.
}
```

Do I need to have an active RunLoop in order to process new mutations on the path?

Comment: Key value observing fires change notifications on the thread that performed the change. Forcing another thread (possibly the main thread) to block waiting for a network request is a bad idea.

Comment: @kevin The blocking is happening on a concurrent queue - not the main thread.

But what if the change to the KVO property happens from a system owned property, like NSWorkspace? (My code/thread does not make the change; I just want to observe it).

Im on macOS.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace

Comment: KVO notifications are fired on the thread that modified the property, it makes no difference who owns the property. For things like NSWorkspace that will almost always be on the main thread.

There is another issue I did not mention previously. In your code example, the function f will actually return long before the change occurs, as you are simply registering your interest in the change.

Comment: @kevin So you can only key-value observe on the main thread? I can not do it on another thread?

The code example shows the issue - that the function returns. I want to know how to 
a) prevent the function returning so it acts like a server 
b) still send changes on the "con" var.